# MVC Ajax: How to send string from view to controller

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I've found a small problem in sending just plain text(string) via ajax compared to sending an json object.

I have currently this setup working

(cs)html

```
<label for="search">
<i class="fa fa-search" onclick="sendtoC()"></i>
<input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Sök här..." autofocus; />
<input type="button" id="SÖK" value="SÖK" onclick="sendtoC()" />
```

Script

```
<script>
var invalue;
var input = document.getElementById("search");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function go (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        invalue = document.getElementById("search").value;
        sendtoC(invalue);
    }
});

function sendtoC() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/SearchResults",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET", 
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', //define a contentType of your request
    cache: false,
    data: { input: invalue },
        success: function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            alert(data.message);
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
}
```

and current controller

```
public ActionResult SearchResults(string input)
    {
        Data.gsPersonLista = db.GetPerson(input);
        return Json(new { success = true, message = input }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }
```

I would like to just send a  straight string to the controller and i tried this Script

```
function sendtoC() {
$.ajax({
url: "/Home/SearchResults",
dataType: "text",
type: "GET", 
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', //define a contentType of your request
cache: false,
data: invalue ,
    success: function (data) {
    if (data.success) {
        alert(data.message);
    }
},
error: function (xhr) {
    alert('error');
}});}
```

with this Controller

```
 public ActionResult SearchResults(string input)
        {
            Data.gsPersonLista = db.GetPerson(input);
            return View(input);


        }
```

however this didn't work, the input string was shown to get value of null and ajax gave error. I currently have no idea of how to fix this nor what gives the error. If someone could Point me in the right direction I would appreciate it

Comment: The string is suppose to be used in a sql Query but I'll deal with that problem after actually attaning the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the `$.get` function here and secondly you should use the `Ùrl.Action` helper for getting the url against the controller action method, as the magic strings would cause issues in deployments where the application might be deployed in sub-directories and in those case the url becomes wrong :

```
$.get('@Url.Action("SearchResults","Home")?input='+invalue , function (data) {  

    if (data.success) {
         alert(data.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: Heyo! This somewhat worked, while debugging "invalue" gets the correct value from the input when it's moved to the new view, however there is no alert from the sucess which is weird.

Comment: try putting: `alert(data)` and see or `console.log(data)` and check on browser console

Answer (score 0):

You can easily pass it as a request parameter, since you've also set the type to "GET".

```
url: "/Home/SearchResults?input="+invalue
```

You also have to remove the data attribute. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATED ANSWER***
datatype is what you are expecting to return from the server. Content type is what you are sending. so to return a view change datatype to htmL.

```
dataType: 'html',
```

the problem is that when you call the function sendtoC you are not receiving any parameters in the function. Change the function to accept a parameter.

```
var invalue;
 var input = document.getElementById("search");
 input.addEventListener("keyup", function go (event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    invalue = document.getElementById("search").value;
    sendtoC(invalue);
}
  });

function sendtoC(invalue ) {
$.ajax({
url: "/Home/SearchResults",
dataType: "json",
type: "GET", 
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', //define a contentType of your request
cache: false,
data: { input: invalue },
    success: function (data) {
    if (data.success) {
        alert(data.message);
    }
},
error: function (xhr) {
    alert('error');
}
});
}
```

Comment: Well this example is of code that already works, the one below it(datatype : text) was the real "problem". Adding the parameter didn't change anything. I shall try adding it to the problematic code tho.